# How to pass predefined stored procedure parameters as variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I tried hard for the past couple of days to solve this problem of calling a stored procedure `sp_oamethod`.

The code below is working fine

```
declare @return int; 
exec @return = sp_oamethod @object,'open(hhtp://xyz.com/uid=abc&pwd=***)';
```

But if I want to pass user id as a variable, I can't:

```
declare @return int;
declare @uid varchar(10);set @uid='abc'

exec @return = sp_oamethod @object, 'open(hhtp://xyz.com/uid='+@uid+'&pwd=***)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on your variable.

`'open(hhtp://xyz.com/uid='+CONVERT(varchar(10),@uid)+'&pwd=***)'`

Comment: i tried this !!

if variable itself varchar type i think again conversion is not required right ?

Answer (score 0):

Define another variable, set it before sp call. Then use it as sp parameter. Like that:

```
declare @return int;
declare @uid varchar(10);set @uid='abc'

declare @url varchar(100);
set @url = 'open(hhtp://xyz.com/uid='+@uid+'&pwd=***)'

exec @return = sp_oamethod @object,@url;
```

[MSDN Passing Values into Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260.aspx)

Comment: This I tried But No Changes,

Even i tried entire stored procedure as transaction query

Comment: Maybe sp_oamethod need nvarchar for second parameter. than you have to convert @uid to nvarchar.

Comment: @uid ,@ url
Now Both With Nvarchar only
But Still Failed calling the page !!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @nvarurl nvarchar(max);
set @nvarurl ='http://example.com?uid='+@uid+'pwd='+pwd+'

exec @return = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open',NULL, 'get',@nvarurl,'false'
```

Done Resolving My Constraint By mysel using above snippset.
Thank you For Those who replied..:)